# Remove selected background (blue)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm working with a custom treeview.  It has an imageHeight property of 80.  Its text is displayed below the node on the screen.  Right now, when a node is selected, a blue box appears (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmHPh.jpg).  *I want this box to go away.  How do I do this?*

My custom treeview code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/UXaJhnA5

Note: the OnPaint event never seems to fire.  I'm lost as to why.

Comment: You are not drawing the background at all.  So you get the default one, blue for the selected node.  Note the use of e.Graphics.FillRectangle() in the [MSDN example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: How do I end up with NO background being highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **DrawMode** property to **OwnerDrawText** and redraw nodes in **DrawNode** event

---

```
    private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Node.Bounds);

            Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
            if (nodeFont == null) nodeFont = ((TreeView)sender).Font;
            nodeFont = new Font(nodeFont.FontFamily, nodeFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Italic);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, Brushes.Black,
                Rectangle.Inflate(e.Bounds, -2, -2));
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your answer provided our team with everything we needed for a major feature enhancement!